# Hide a <article> if has an empty src"" with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i hide the below article if the $img is empty ?

```
<article data-stars="<?php echo $StarRating[6];?>" name="<?php echo $Price[6];?>" class="box">
<img width="270" height="160" alt="" src="<?php echo $img[6][1];?>"></a>
<div>Content</div>
</article>
```

I am filtering the same aricle(s) with two jquery filters 
Price Filter:

```
tjq(document).ready(function() {
      tjq("#price-range").slider({
          range: true,
          min: 0,
          max: 3000,
          values: [ 1, 2000 ],
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
              tjq(".min-price-label").html( "€" + ui.values[ 0 ]);
              tjq(".max-price-label").html( "€" + ui.values[ 1 ]);

              $('article[data-price]').each(function() {
                  var dPrice = $(this).attr('data-price');
                  if ( dPrice < ui.values[ 0 ] || dPrice > ui.values[ 1 ] ) 
                      $(this).hide();
                  else
                      $(this).show();
              });
          }
      });
```

And Star rating filter

```
 $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(e){
  $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
  grabVal = $(this).val();
          if(!$(this).is(":checked")){
  $("article[data-stars='"+grabVal+"']").hide();
          }else{
  $("article[data-stars='"+grabVal+"']").show();
          }
      });

          if(!$("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")){
  $("article").show();   
      }
  });
```

And the last filter for this articles is :
Show less/more

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#hotel-list article:gt(4)').hide();
  $('#loadMore').click(function () {
  $('#hotel-list article:hidden:lt(2)').show();
      });
  $('#showLess').click(function () {
  $('#hotel-list article').not(':lt(4)').hide();
      });
  });
```

Could you please help me create another filter to hide the aricles that have an empty img,

Comment: Or to combine all the above and create a jquery filter for price and stars
And one jquery script to hide the articles with empty img and the functionality of the showless/more script

Comment: As I see it, that should rather be done server-side cause else you would on purpose load useless content... and anyway you're already doing stuff server-side !

Comment: @Bartdude what do you mean by server side ?

Comment: I mean in PHP. If you don't know the difference then you might want to learn some more things before coding for web

Answer (score 1):

I give you this JSFiddle.

With it you can hide the  if your img src is empty.

I put a class on the  and with this code you can do what you want.

```
    $('.myClass').each(function(){
       if($(this).attr('src') == ""){
          $(this).closest('article').hide();
       }
    });
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/k7kt33hk/)

Comment: it work, but when i apply the price or starts filer or load more it shows those articles without img

Comment: The easier way is to make a function with the code i give you and call the code after your price or starts filter.

The best way is in each filter you look what you want and the src img in the current article

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be the shortest way of hiding all articles with an empty img?

```
$("article img[src=""]").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```